# How to pass an array of param values via GET to a controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Within a Rails app I have an API controller that accepts query parameters

```
module Api
  class UserController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @users = User.where(query_params)
    end
    def query_params    
      params.permit( :id, :name)
    end
  end
end
```

I want to be able to pass multiple IDs to this controller action via a get request.

```
api_users_path(id: User.my_scoped_selection.map(&:id) )
```

this generates a URL with the ID array indicated by square brackets

```
http://my.app/api/users?id[]=1
```

I have also tried manually typing in the addressbar

```
http://my.app/api/users?id=1,2,3
http://my.app/api/users?id=1&id=2&id=3
http://my.app/api/users?id[0]=1&id[1]=2&id[2]=3
```

None of which correctly filter the Users, and I am getting all Users returned.

How should I format a URL to correctly pass an array of param values? Or, how should I construct the controller to handle multiple param values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For strong parameters to permit an array of id, you could try

```
def query_params
  params.permit(id: [], :name)
end
```

For URL to send an array of ids

```
http://my.app/api/users?id[]=1,2,3
```

Comment: doh! I had not even considered this being a strong params issue, and was too focussed on the format of the url. Thanks @kenny, this worked perfectly!